# trying to replace string in array with integer value

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to replace strings inside an array with integer values, here is the bit of code:

```
for i in Data:
if (Data[i,4] == "STANDING"):
        Data[i,4] = 1
    else:
        Data[i,4] = 0
    i+=1
```

and here's the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/MIU/4th year/Graduation
>   Project/Graduation/SVM.py", line 19, in 
>   `if (Data[i,4] == "STANDING"): IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of   integer (or boolean) type`

What can I do?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We do not know what is contained in `Data` do we?

Comment: Data probably doesn't contain integers. You might be able to just use `i[4]` in place of `Data[i,4]` I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

do not increment the variable in for loops.

Comment: on the assumption that you have a 2D matrix and want to iterate the rows and index at the 5th column

Answer (score 0):

The error
`IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`
means you are trying to use a string as an iterator instead of an integer. I would look at the values inside of Data to make sure they are ints. If they are strings of numbers ('1', '2', '3', etc.) I would simply cast them to int.

`Data = list(map(int, Data))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast test you can do it using this simple loop.

```
    Data = ["here", "prueba", "STANDING"]
    for i in range(0,len(Data)):
        if(Data[i] == "STANDING"):
            Data[i] = 1
        else:
            Data[i] = 0
        i = i + 1
```